# python - grouping results in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I got loops, that produces data like that:
**host1 vm1

host1 vm2

host2 vm3

host2 vm4

host1 vm5**
...

Goal:
I want to group them in a dictionary like that:
**my_list = [{'host1': ['vm2', 'vm5']}, {'host2': ['vm3', 'vm4']}]**

Thanks in advance!
Regards

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(list)
for host, vm in my_list:
    my_dict[host] += [vm]

print(dict(my_dict))
```

Output:

```
{'host1': ['vm1', 'vm2', 'vm5'], 'host2': ['vm3', 'vm4']}
```